# Setting Background Color on JPanel with MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, thread-sleep, mouse-listeners

I am attempting to create a game of life simulator:

My code basically consists of a JFrame holding a grid of JPanels, and a corresponding sized 2d boolean array where each JPanel is specifically an instance of a class that extends JPanel

This class:
initializes the JPAnel to a set Size, makes it opaque, sets its background color (this all works) and adds a mouseListener to it which changes the color of the JPanel based on the value of the 2d boolean array in corresponding location before switching the value of the array.

I also pass the boolean array as a reference so that way each tile is carrying the same boolean array and they all can flip its values.

For some reason, the only background color the JPanel holds is the one I set during initialization. After that the JPanel does not change its background color, despite the mouseListener registering that it has been pressed, and furthermore despite the successful call of a repaint() method. Can someone please explain what on earth is going on? I don't have anything to go off of for debugging since everything seems to be right in place.

(the individual Conway Tile)

```
package conweezy;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TheTile extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    boolean[][] thearray;
    int xindex;
    int yindex;
    public TheTile(double width, double height, int xloc, int yloc, boolean[][] inputworld, int i, int j)
    {
        super();
        setSize((int)width, (int)height); setLocation(xloc, yloc); 
        thearray = inputworld; xindex = i; yindex = j; setLayout(null); 
        setOpaque(true);
        if(!thearray[xindex][yindex])
        {               
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if(thearray[xindex][yindex])
        {                
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        setVisible(true);
        //addMouseListener(this);       
    }        

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(!thearray[xindex][yindex])
        {                
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            System.out.println(xindex + " " + yindex);
            repaint();                
        }
        if(!thearray[xindex][yindex])
        {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            repaint();                
        }
        thearray[xindex][yindex] = !thearray[xindex][yindex];
        repaint();            
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {            
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {            
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {            
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {            
    }
}
```

.

```
(The Conway Grid):


package conweezy;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TheUniverseFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static boolean[][] universalframe;
    public TheTile[][] universaltiles;
    boolean threadstate = false;
    TheUniverseFrame(double xsize, double ysize, int tilexcount, int tileycount)
    {
        //set constants
        setTitle("Welcome to the Game of Life: Datatronic Existence");
        universalframe = new boolean[tilexcount][tileycount];
        universaltiles = new TheTile[tilexcount][tileycount];
        setSize((int)xsize+100, (int)ysize);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        //initialize tiles and boolean array
        int i = 0;
        int j;
        setVisible(true);
        while(i < tilexcount)
        {
            j = 0;
            while(j < tileycount)
            {
                universalframe[i][j] = false;
                universaltiles[i][j] = new TheTile(xsize/((double)tilexcount), //tile width
                                                   ysize/((double)tileycount), //tile height
                                                   (int)(xsize/((double)tilexcount))*i, //tile x position
                                                    (int)(ysize/((double)tileycount))*j, //tile y position
                                                    universalframe, //boolean array
                                                     i, j); //tile position on array
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {

                }
                //universaltiles[i][j].addMouseListener(universaltiles[i][j]);

                add(universaltiles[i][j]);
                repaint();
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }            
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }
}
```

The Main Class:

```
package conweezy;


public class Conweezy 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TheUniverseFrame theGame = new TheUniverseFrame(500,500,20,20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working variation of your example that toggles a pixel's background color when clicked. Note,

- Use [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) to run on the EDT.
- Remember to `pack()` the enclosing frame.
- Call `setVisible()` once.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to establish a tile's size.

[image]

As tested:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Conweezy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TheUniverseFrame theGame = new TheUniverseFrame(500, 500, 20, 20);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class TheUniverseFrame extends JFrame {

        public static boolean[][] universalframe;
        public TheTile[][] universaltiles;
        boolean threadstate = false;

        TheUniverseFrame(double xsize, double ysize, int tilexcount, int tileycount) {
            //set constants
            setTitle("Welcome to the Game of Life: Datatronic Existence");
            universalframe = new boolean[tilexcount][tileycount];
            universaltiles = new TheTile[tilexcount][tileycount];
            setLayout(new GridLayout(tilexcount, tileycount));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //initialize tiles and boolean array
            int i = 0;
            int j;
            while (i < tilexcount) {
                j = 0;
                while (j < tileycount) {
                    universalframe[i][j] = false;
                    universaltiles[i][j] = new TheTile(xsize / ((double) tilexcount), //tile width
                        ysize / ((double) tileycount), //tile height
                        (int) (xsize / ((double) tilexcount)) * i, //tile x position
                        (int) (ysize / ((double) tileycount)) * j, //tile y position
                        universalframe, //boolean array
                        i, j); //tile position on array
                    add(universaltiles[i][j]);
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private static class TheTile extends JPanel {

        boolean[][] thearray;
        int xindex;
        int yindex;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(25, 25);
        }

        public TheTile(double width, double height, int xloc, int yloc, boolean[][] inputworld, int i, int j) {
            thearray = inputworld;
            xindex = i;
            yindex = j;
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    thearray[xindex][yindex] = !thearray[xindex][yindex];
                    if (thearray[xindex][yindex]) {
                        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println(xindex + " " + yindex);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the superfluous `xsize` and `ysize` parameters left as a re-factoring exercise.